# Extracting only certain nodes in web scraping on R

Tags: html, css, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to extract some soccer data from the fbref.com site, specifically I should extract some dates and I would like to understand how to filter the various nodes within the site
Hello, I would like to extract some data from fbref but I cannot extract only a certain type of data. I will explain better by attaching the html code in question:

```
<th scope="row" class="left " data-stat=**"date"** csk="20230819"><a href="/it/partite/254420f7/Internazionale-Monza-19-Agosto-2023-Serie-A">19-08-2023</a></th>
    <a href="/it/partite/254420f7/Internazionale-Monza-19-Agosto-2023-Serie-A">19-08-2023</a>
```

Reading the code:

```
url <- https://fbref.com/it/squadre/d609edc0/Statistiche-Internazionale

html_data <- read_html(url)

html_data %>%
  html_nodes(".left ")
```

It reads more or less 1266 different nodes, but I am only interested in extracting the text where "data-stats='date'. By getting only those nodes I should be able to later extract the date after the "href".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use the `html_attr()` function to extract out the value in the attribute and check to see if it is the desired value.

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://fbref.com/it/squadre/d609edc0/Statistiche-Internazionale"

html_data <- read_html(url)

foundnodes <- html_data %>% html_nodes(".left ") 

#extract the attribute and check to see if it is equal to date
nodes_date <- which(html_attr(foundnodes, "data-stat")=="date")

#subset the foundnodes
foundnodes[nodes_date]
```

Or do it one statement with:

```
#find the nodes with class = .left then check that attribute "data-stat" is equal to "date"    
html_data  %>% html_elements(".left[data-stat='date']")
```